# Prevent svn from outputtting unnecessary diff lines

Tags: svn

For one particular source file, I generated a reference patch file using `TortoiseMerge`. The patch file shows only lines where an actual change occurs. For example:

```
@@ -87 +87 @@
-                Particles(I)%Mass
+                MassArray(I)
@@ -91 +91 @@
-                  Particles(I)%Mass
+                  MassArray(I)
```

However when I use the command line `diff` option this is what I get

`svn diff --old FileName.FOR@6382 --new FileName.FOR@6383`

```
@@ -84,11 +84,11 @@
               end if
               TotalParticleMass = &
                 TotalParticleMass + &
-                Particles(I)%Mass
+                MassArray(I)
               if (IsVirtualParticle(I)) then
                 TotalVirtualParticleMass =  &
                   TotalVirtualParticleMass + &
-                  Particles(I)%Mass
+                  MassArray(I)
               end if
             end do
             write(TVMunit, '(I12, G12.4, G12.4, I12, I12, I12)')  &
```

As you can see the file generated by the command line also includes lines which are not different. I really don't need this information for my current purposes.

How can I just get the modified lines using the command line? I need something identical to the patch file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use external `diff` with `-U0` option (number lines of unified context):

```
svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x'-U0' ...
```